# Why "loadNibNamed" methods return array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nib, nsbundle, loadnibnamed

When we use the loadNibNamed method to get nib file, why will return a array, is not a nib file name corresponds to a nib file? I try to print this array's count, I found it always return 1. I hope you can help me to explain, thank you every much! Here is the snippet of code :

```
 NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TestView" owner:self options:nil];
 NSLog(@"array's count is %ld",array.count);
```

Comment: Have you also testes xib files with more than one view inside? This is why this method returns array. a xib can contain more than one view.

Comment: oh, I see, thanks.I drag a ViewController to the xib file and found it return 2. :)

Answer (score 3):

This is because NIB/xib files can also contain more than one view representation. So within the array you can access all of the contained views.

Answer (score 3):

The reason that xib return an array is that **".XIB" can contain multiple views**. The advantage is that you don't have to create one xib file for one view. You simply just put multiple views into one XIB and access it from an array

**Example**
.Xib --> array[view1, view2, view3, view4]

You can see from image
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41553861/when-using-loadnibnamed-why-do-we-have-to-use-first-dont-we-want-to-decouple):

This is a legacy design left over from the early days of ProjectBuilder/PBX/Interface Builder. I would strongly not recommend this approach and just use separate xib files. I do not see any benefit.

However if decided to still do it, you can have multiple views as such.

[image]

And access View with .first or `[0]`, view-2 with `[1]` and so on. Having that said in the comments JAL has said it's not guaranteed to return the indexes correctly and it's better to `switch`, `filter` or use `tag`s for the views.

Comment: Not sure if you saw, but the image I linked you (and the one in this answer) come from the other answer to this question.

Comment: @JAL No I didn't see :D